# How do I get the columns of a postgresql database into a Python list?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to get the column names of a table from a PostgreSQL database and then get them into a python list.
I don't really know how to get the column names. I tried:

```sql
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = "my_table"
```

I think there is probably an easier way. Do you know how to do it easily?

The next problem I have is that I want to do all that in Python and I'm kinda new to it. My goal is to save the column names in a list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is right and this is the most convenient way of doing such things.

After executing your query just append them to some list

```py
columns = []
rows = db.execute('select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = "my_table"')
for row in rows:
    columns.append(row['column_name']) # or row[0] i think.

print(columns)
```

Comment: Also you can do,
```[column[0] for column in cursor.description]```

I assume you have already done cursor thing.